# Error on the function create_engine().execute() from sqlalchemy library on kaggle notebook

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to load data from kaggle on pandas, then, using .to_sql() function:

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df_1 = pd.read_csv("../input/bart-ridership/date-hour-soo-dest-2016.csv")
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
df_1.to_sql("table", con=engine)
result = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
```

But it is throwing the next error:

```
    586 
    587     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 588         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    589 
    590     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):

OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "table": syntax error
[SQL: SELECT * FROM table]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TABLE` is SQLite's keyword - use some other name for your table.

E.g.:

```
df_1.to_sql("my_table", con=engine)
result = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table")
```